# Ionic serve -lab get an error after update script

Tags: ionic3

I'm facing an error when i update my script . here is what i mean

First normally run `Ionic serve -lab`

here is the result, (working fine)

```
$ ionic serve -lab
Starting app-scripts server: --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --dev-logger-port 53703 --nobrowser --lab - Ctrl+C to cancel
[09:56:49]  watch started ...
[09:56:49]  build dev started ...
[09:56:49]  clean started ...
[09:56:49]  clean finished in 8 ms
[09:56:49]  copy started ...
[09:56:49]  deeplinks started ...
[09:56:49]  deeplinks finished in 136 ms
[09:56:49]  transpile started ...
[09:56:56]  transpile finished in 6.74 s
[09:56:56]  preprocess started ...
[09:56:56]  preprocess finished in less than 1 ms
[09:56:56]  webpack started ...
[09:56:57]  copy finished in 7.53 s
[09:57:09]  webpack finished in 12.60 s
[09:57:09]  sass started ...
[09:57:11]  sass finished in 2.35 s
[09:57:11]  postprocess started ...
[09:57:11]  postprocess finished in 16 ms
[09:57:11]  lint started ...
[09:57:11]  build dev finished in 22.45 s
[09:57:11]  watch ready in 22.60 s
[09:57:11]  dev server running: http://localhost:8100/

[OK] Development server running!
     Local: http://localhost:8100
     External: http://192.168.3.223:8100
     DevApp: StoreMobile@8100 on DESKTOP-3OF111S

[09:57:17]  lint finished in 5.93 s
```

then, i want to change my script (source code) a bit. I just randomly adding a string in my html then i get an error. Here is the error

```
[OK] Development server running!
     Local: http://localhost:8100
     External: http://192.168.3.223:8100
     DevApp: StoreMobile@8100 on DESKTOP-3OF111S

[09:57:17]  lint finished in 5.93 s
[09:59:09]  build started ...
[09:59:09]  deeplinks update started ...
[09:59:09]  deeplinks update finished in 19 ms
[09:59:09]  template update started ...
[09:59:09]  template update finished in 32 ms
[09:59:09]  build finished in 55 ms

events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:568:26)
```

Well , i can run `ionic serve -lab` again but, i'm to `lazy` for it . So, how can i fix this ? sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

Just saw a solution on [github](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2921) the problem seem to be caused by a chrome update.

The following solutions seem to work

- **NOT** using google chrome eg `ionic serve -w firefox`
- Instaling this specific version of ws `npm install ws@3.3.2 --save-dev --save-exact`
- Updating `ionic/app-scripts` to `@3.1.6` *("worked for me")*

Answer (score 0):

same here :(

```
[17:15:53]  lint finished in 9.50 s 
[17:16:39]  build started ... 
[17:16:39]  deeplinks update started ... 
[17:16:39]  deeplinks update finished in 134 ms 
[17:16:39]  template update started ... 
[17:16:39]  template update finished in 6 ms 
[17:16:39]  build finished in 160 ms 

events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:568:26)
```

EDIT & solution:
Searching about it I found this https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-serve-crash-on-save/115615/22 and just using safari instead of chrome there's no problem anymore.